# Custom block Block Validation failure w/ deprecation declared

Tags: block-editor, validation

I am running into a custom block validation issue from some markup changes in the block html. I am wondering what I am missing about the deprecation as it's being hit but not validating the old markup no matter what i've tried.

When loading the page editor I am seeing:

> This block contains unexpected or invalid content.
> **Attempt Block Recovery**

on every old block version that was on the page before the update, and this error message in devtools console:

```
Block validation: Block validation failed for `chris/accordion` (Object).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="wp-block wp-block-chris-accordion-wrapper"><h3><button id="accordionButton-213b088660226" class="wp-block-chris-accordion accordion-align-left" style="border-radius:22px 22px 22px 22px;box-shadow:0px 2px 20px #00000078;border-width:14px 14px 14px 14px;border-style:solid;border-color:transparent" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordionContent-213b088660226"><span class="wp-block-chris-accordion--heading">Test Accordion</span><span class="wp-block-chris-accordion-icon"><span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-arrow-down-alt2 closed" style="color:#000;font-size:16"></span><span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-arrow-up-alt2 open" style="color:#000;font-size:16"></span></span></button></h3><div id="accordionContent-213b088660226" class="wp-block-chris-accordion--content " role="region" aria-labelledby="accordionButton-213b088660226"></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="wp-block wp-block-chris-accordion-wrapper"><button id="accordionButton-213b088660226" class="wp-block-chris-accordion accordion-align-left" style="border-radius:22px 22px 22px 22px;box-shadow:0px 2px 20px #00000078;border-width:14px 14px 14px 14px;border-style:solid;border-color:transparent" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordionContent-213b088660226"><h3 class="wp-block-chris-accordion--heading">Test Accordion</h3><span class="wp-block-chris-accordion-icon"><span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-arrow-down-alt2 closed" style="color:#000;font-size:16"></span><span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-arrow-up-alt2 open" style="color:#000;font-size:16"></span></span></button><div id="accordionContent-213b088660226" class="wp-block-chris-accordion--content" role="region" aria-labelledby="accordionButton-213b088660226">

</div></div>
```

Original save function:

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps, RichText, InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Icon } from "@wordpress/components";
import classnames from "classnames";

export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const {
        text,
        alignment,
        headingLevel,
        uniqueID,
        expandedOnLoad,
        shadow,
        buttonRadius,
        iconColor,
        iconSize,
        iconIcon,
        iconActiveIcon,
        buttonBorder,
        buttonBorderColor
    } = attributes;
    const classes = classnames(`accordion-align-${alignment}`);
    const CustomHeading = headingLevel;
    return (
        <div className="wp-block wp-block-chris-accordion-wrapper">
            <CustomHeading>
                <button
                    {...useBlockProps.save({
                        id: `accordionButton-${uniqueID}`,
                        className: classes,
                        style: {
                            borderRadius: `${buttonRadius.top} ${buttonRadius.right} ${buttonRadius.bottom} ${buttonRadius.left}`,
                            boxShadow: `${shadow.x} ${shadow.y} ${shadow.blur} ${shadow.color}`,
                            borderWidth: `${buttonBorder.top} ${buttonBorder.right} ${buttonBorder.bottom} ${buttonBorder.left}`,
                            borderStyle: "solid",
                            borderColor: buttonBorderColor
                        },
                    })}
                    aria-expanded={expandedOnLoad}
                    aria-controls={`accordionContent-${uniqueID}`}
                >
                    <RichText.Content
                        className="wp-block-chris-accordion--heading"
                        tagName="span"
                        value={text}
                    />
                    <span className="wp-block-chris-accordion-icon">
                        <Icon
                            icon={iconIcon}
                            className={__("closed", "accordion")}
                            style={{ color: iconColor, fontSize: iconSize }}
                        />
                        <Icon
                            icon={iconActiveIcon}
                            className={__("open", "accordion")}
                            style={{ color: iconColor, fontSize: iconSize }}
                        />
                    </span>
                </button>
            </CustomHeading>
            <div
                id={`accordionContent-${uniqueID}`}
                className="wp-block-chris-accordion--content"
                role="region"
                aria-labelledby={`accordionButton-${uniqueID}`}
            >
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

New save function:

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps, RichText, InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Icon } from "@wordpress/components";
import classnames from "classnames";

export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const {
        text,
        alignment,
        headingLevel,
        uniqueID,
        expandedOnLoad,
        shadow,
        buttonRadius,
        iconColor,
        iconSize,
        iconIcon,
        iconActiveIcon,
        buttonBorder,
        buttonBorderColor
    } = attributes;
    const classes = classnames(`accordion-align-${alignment}`);
    const CustomHeading = headingLevel;
    return (
        <div className="wp-block wp-block-chris-accordion-wrapper">
            <CustomHeading>
                <button
                    {...useBlockProps.save({
                        id: `accordionButton-${uniqueID}`,
                        className: classes,
                        style: {
                            borderRadius: `${buttonRadius.top} ${buttonRadius.right} ${buttonRadius.bottom} ${buttonRadius.left}`,
                            boxShadow: `${shadow.x} ${shadow.y} ${shadow.blur} ${shadow.color}`,
                            borderWidth: `${buttonBorder.top} ${buttonBorder.right} ${buttonBorder.bottom} ${buttonBorder.left}`,
                            borderStyle: "solid",
                            borderColor: buttonBorderColor
                        },
                    })}
                    aria-expanded={expandedOnLoad}
                    aria-controls={`accordionContent-${uniqueID}`}
                >
                    <RichText.Content
                        className="wp-block-chris-accordion--heading"
                        tagName="span"
                        value={text}
                    />
                    <span className="wp-block-chris-accordion-icon">
                        <Icon
                            icon={iconIcon}
                            className={__("closed", "accordion")}
                            style={{ color: iconColor, fontSize: iconSize }}
                        />
                        <Icon
                            icon={iconActiveIcon}
                            className={__("open", "accordion")}
                            style={{ color: iconColor, fontSize: iconSize }}
                        />
                    </span>
                </button>
            </CustomHeading>
            <div
                id={`accordionContent-${uniqueID}`}
                className={`wp-block-chris-accordion--content ${expandedOnLoad ? 'open' : ''}`}
                role="region"
                aria-labelledby={`accordionButton-${uniqueID}`}
            >
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Deprecation:

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps, RichText, InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Icon } from "@wordpress/components";
import classnames from "classnames";
import blockData from "../block.json";

const v025 = {
  supports: {
    html: true,
    spacing: {
      margin: true,
      padding: true
    },
    color: {
      text: true,
      background: true,
      link: true
    }
  },
  attributes: {
    ...blockData.attributes
  },
  save({ attributes }) {
    const {
      text,
      alignment,
      headingLevel,
      uniqueID,
      expandedOnLoad,
      shadow,
      buttonRadius,
      iconColor,
      iconSize,
      iconIcon,
      iconActiveIcon,
      buttonBorder,
      buttonBorderColor
    } = attributes;
    const classes = classnames(`accordion-align-${alignment}`);
    return (
      <div className="wp-block wp-block-chris-accordion-wrapper">
        <button
          {...useBlockProps.save({
            id: `accordionButton-${uniqueID}`,
            className: classes,
            style: {
              borderRadius: `${buttonRadius.top} ${buttonRadius.right} ${buttonRadius.bottom} ${buttonRadius.left}`,
              boxShadow: `${shadow.x} ${shadow.y} ${shadow.blur} ${shadow.color}`,
              borderWidth: `${buttonBorder.top} ${buttonBorder.right} ${buttonBorder.bottom} ${buttonBorder.left}`,
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderColor: buttonBorderColor
            },
          })}
          aria-expanded={expandedOnLoad}
          aria-controls={`accordionContent-${uniqueID}`}
        >
          <RichText.Content
            className="wp-block-chris-accordion--heading"
            tagName={headingLevel}
            value={text}
          />
          <span className="wp-block-chris-accordion-icon">
            <Icon
              icon={iconIcon}
              className={__("closed", "accordion")}
              style={{ color: iconColor, fontSize: iconSize }}
            />
            <Icon
              icon={iconActiveIcon}
              className={__("open", "accordion")}
              style={{ color: iconColor, fontSize: iconSize }}
            />
          </span>
        </button>
        <div
          id={`accordionContent-${uniqueID}`}
          className="wp-block-chris-accordion--content"
          role="region"
          aria-labelledby={`accordionButton-${uniqueID}`}
        >
          <InnerBlocks.Content />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default v025;
```